# What is the difference between static array declaration and pointer array declaration when returning an array from the function in c

Tags: arrays, c

Here CODE A doesn't give any error where as CODE B gives error saying that assignment to expression of array type,

What actual is the difference between CODE A and CODE B ?

```
int *input_array(int n)
{
  int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  printf("Enter the elements of array: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  return array;
} 
int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter the no.of elements : ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int *array;
  array = input_array(n);     CODE A // successful 
    
  int array2[n];
  array2 = input_array(n);    CODE B // error
}
```

Comment: arrays cannot be assigned. You will find this in any decent [c book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Arrays cannot be returned either.  There is no way to express it, on account of the automatic conversion of values of array type to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*>> What actual is the difference between CODE A and CODE B ?*

Couple of points to remember:

- Arrays are not pointers. They are different<sup>1)</sup>.
- In C, array names are non *modifiable* lvalues<sup>2)</sup>.

Note that, in your code, the `input_array()` function is returning `int` pointer and not array. Arrays cannot be returned but you can return pointer to initial element of an array from a function<sup>3)</sup>.

In `CODE A`, you are assigning `input_array()` function return value to an `int` pointer named `array`. The type of `array` variable and return type of `input_array()` function is same. Hence, the assignment is perfectly valid.

`CODE B` is invalid because you are attempting to assign to `array2` which is an array of `int` type and , in C, array names are non *modifiable* lvalues. You cannot assign anything to an array variable but can only initialise/modify the array members.

---

1). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer).

2). From C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p1 *[emphasis added]*

> ....  A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

3). When you access an array, it is *converted* to a pointer to first element but there are few **exceptions** to this rule:
From C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p3 *[emphasis added]*

> 3 Except **when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array**, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is **converted** to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. ....